# duply: using variables in pre script?

Tags: variables, duplicity-backup

I'm using duply/duplicity to backup our servers. In the pre script I want to use the $SOURCE variable to dump mysql databases into it. But the variable is not usable as mentioned in the documentation. :-(

Here's my pre script

```
echo "source: ${SOURCE}"
```

and the output is:

```
Output: source:
```

PS: pre file is executable (700).
PS

Answer (score 0):

that's a bug in current duply.

[EDIT]
fixed in duply 1.9.0 ..
[/EDIT]

as a workaround remove the executable flag from your script unless you need a different interpreter than bash. the next duply release will address this issue.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what your workaround will cause.

Comment: did you try it? ..ede/duply.net